# Sum values based on first occurrence of other column using excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I have the following two columns in excel spreadsheet

```
A   B
1   10
1   10
1   10
2   20
3   5
3   5
```

and I would like to sum the values from B-column that represents the first occurrence of the value in A-column using a formula. So I expect to get the following result:

```
result = B1+B4+B5 = 35
```

i.e., sum column B where any unique value exists in the same row but Column A. In my case if `Ai = Aj`, then `Bi=Bj`, where `i,j` represents the row positions. It means that if two rows from A-column have the same value, then its corresponding values from B-column are the same. I can have the value sorted by column A values, but I prefer to have a formula that works regardless of sorting.

I found this [post](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=59420) that refers to the same problem, but the proposed solution I am not able to understand.

Comment: You could probably just sum unique. I'm sure google can find an array formula for that.

Comment: I made several searches but I did not find a solution for my specific problem. [This](https://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/06/25/sum-only-if-unique-value-in-another-column-in-excel/) is the nearest one I have found but is not my exact problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT and COUNTIF:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B6/COUNTIF(A1:A6,A1:A6))
```

[image]

Here the step by step explanation:

1. `COUNTIF(A1:A6, A1:A6)` will produce an array with the frequency of the values: `A1:A6`. In our case it will be: `{3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2}`
2. Then we have to do the following division: `{10, 10, 10, 20, 5, 5}/{3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2}`. The result will be: `{3.33, 3.33, 3.33, 20, 2.5, 2.5}`. It replaces each value by the average of its group.
3. Summing the result we will get: `(3.33+3.33+3.33) + 20 + (2.5+2.5=35)=35`.

Using the above trick we can just get the same result as if we just sum the first element of each group from the column `A`.

---

To make this dynamic, so it grows and shrinks with the data set use this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,B:B))/COUNTIF($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,B:B)),$A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,B:B))))
```

Comment: It works, but just when including the exact non-empty rows, if I want to extend the formula for empty rows it does not work. For example, if I delete the last row then I get `#DIV/0!`

Comment: Is the data contiguous, no blanks between the values?

Comment: Yes, in my case, no blanks in between, just at the end.

Comment: It works including blank lines at the end, the only thing is that I get the message about circular reference when all columns are empty. I am using this formula in a template file that has to be filled by another person, so it works with data, but not without data.

Comment: Then wrap it in an `IF(COUNT(B:B),formula,"")`

Answer (score 2):

... or just SUMPRODUCT.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B7, --(A2:A7<>A1:A6))
```

[image]

Comment: Though the OP did say, `but I prefer to have a formula that works regardless of sorting.`

Comment: I copied the formula and I get 25 instead of 35.

Comment: Well, seeing as how I did **not** use photoshop to generate the supplied image perhaps you should use Formulas, Formula Auditing, Evaluate Formula to figure out what is wrong.